# How can I get F# Interactive window to use the same path as the project?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

In my project I am opening a file with some relative path to the executable. I was trying to test my code in the F# Interractive window, but it seems to run from a completely different path. How can I change the path/ make it run from the same path as the project?

Answer (score 9):

I think [`__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233234.aspx) identifier could help here.

You should use [compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx) to separate between using F# Interactive and compiling F# project.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
  let path = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + some_relative_path
#else
  let path = another_relative_path
#endif
```

Comment: Nice! This works even if you highlight some code in a file and "Execute in Interactive".

Answer (score 3):

You could set the current working directory when running in FSI:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("<project_path>")
#endif
```